# How to achieve type stability when assigning values with StaticArrays?

Tags: julia

I have the following struct (simplified), and some calculations done with this struct:

```
mutable struct XX{VecType}
 v::VecType
end

long_calculation(x::XX) = sum(x.v)
```

as a part of the program i need to update the `v` value. the struct is callable and mainly used as a cache. here, the use of static arrays helps a lot in speeding up calculations, but the type of v is ultimately defined by an user. my problem lies when assigning new values to `XX.v`:

```
function (f::XX)(w)
  f.v .= w #here lies the problem
  return long_calculation(f)
```

this works if `v <: Array` and `w` is of any value, but it doesn't work when `v <: StaticArrays.StaticArray`, as `setindex!` is not defined on that type.

How can i write `f.v .= w` in a way that, when `v` allows it, performs an inplace modification, but when not, just creates a new value, and stores it in the `XX` struct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a package for exactly this use case: [`BangBang.jl`](https://github.com/JuliaFolds/BangBang.jl).  From there, you can use [`setindex!!`](https://juliafolds.github.io/BangBang.jl/dev/#BangBang.setindex!!):

```
f.v = setindex!!(f.v, w)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here I propose a simple solution that should be enough in most cases. Use multiple dispatch and define the following function:

```
my_assign!(f::XX, w) = (f.v .= w)
my_assign!(f::XX{<:StaticArray}, w) = (f.v = w)
```

and then simply call it in your code like this:

```
function (f::XX)(w)
    my_assign!(f, w)
    return long_calculation(f)
end
```

Then if you (or your users) get an error with a default implementation it is easy enough to add another method to `my_assign!` co cover other special cases when it throws an error.

Would such a solution be enough for you?

Comment: I finally opted to use BangBang.jl, but this a good solution too